# Denote $Z$ as the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$. Find the maximum, of the number of points in $Z \cap V$.

Tags: vector-spaces, contest-math

Denote $Z$ as the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$. Let $k$ be given, $0 \leq k \leq n$. Find the maximum, over all vector subspaces $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $k$, of the number of points in $Z \cap V$.

My attempt: Since $\dim(V)=k$, it has $k$ linear independent vectors. Thus, the maximum number of points is $2^k$.

Is my proof correct? It seems a bit too easy.

Remark: The question is taken from the book 'Putnam and Beyond', page $78$.

Comment: You've shown that you can get $2^k$ of the vectors of $Z$ inside a $V$ of dimension $k$ (take, for instance, the $V$ spanned by the $k$ vectors $(1, 0,\ldots,0), (0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$). But how can you _know_ that it's not possible to cram $2^k + 1$ of them in there?

Answer (score -1):

we do have $2^n$ of these points one of them is the 0-vector. There are $2^{n-1}$ linearly independent vectors. If V has dimension k then it can have at most k of these vectors plus the 0-vector and this adds up to k+1.